# Attribute error why Enumerated data type?

Tags: python, class, exception, enumerated-types

It will work if I do `AnimalsENUM(35).Name = 'TIGER'`, but not if I set the `Name` with a function. Why?

```
class AnimalsENUM():
    def __init__(self,N):
        try:
            if N not in range(101):
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            print("Animal Number %s is not vaild" % (Number))
        self.__Number = N
        self.__Name = ''
        self.__Age = None
        self.__Location = None
```

Function to set the name

```
def SetName(self):
    while True:
        try:
            Name = str(input("input name in all caps"))
            if Name not in ('TIGER', 'MONKEY','ELEPHANT', None):
                raise ValueError
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Animal name %s not valid" % (Name))
    self.__Name = Name

def SetLocation__(self):
        while True:
            try:
                Location = int(input("input name in all caps"))
                if Location not in range(21):
                    raise ValueError
            except ValueError:
                print("Animal Location %s not vaild" % (Location))
        self.__Location = Location

def SetAge(self):
        while True:
            try:
                Age = int(input("input name in all caps"))
                if Age not in (range(100)):
                    raise ValueError
            except ValueError:
                print("Animal Age %s not vaild" % (Age))
```

I should be able to print this and print the animal name all in caps

```
c = AnimalsENUM(25)
c.SetName()
print(c.Name)
```

Comment: You have no `Name` attribute. You have a `__Name` attribute (which gets mangled to `_AnimalsNum__Name`). If you want the attribute to be public, use `self.Name = ..` instead.

Comment: So, yes, setting `AnimalsENUM(35).Name = 'TIGER'` works, because then you are setting that attribute directly. Why do you expect `self.__Name` to be the same thing as `self.Name`?

Comment: So I need to change both self.__name to self.name ? I don't understand what you mean by your first comment? Thank you for you help by the way

Comment: I want to set the attribute with the use of SetName.

Comment: The `__<variablename>` variable names are special, they are 'mangled' to prevent clashes between subclasses, so Python transforms any such name to include `_<ClassName>` as a prefix, under the hood. You should never use such names unless you specifically want to protect attributes from clashing in subclasses.

Comment: Yes, just rename all `self.__name` variables to `self.name`. Do the same for your other double-underscore names.